# In yahoo pipe how to combine two page content into one(and after that rename it into content:encoded)?

Tags: rss, feed, yahoo-pipes

When use "fetch page" module, you can get the content of the page and assign it to a item's variable.

Here's what I want to do.
I want to fetch two pages's content and assign to item.data1 and item.data2.
And then I want to combine these two data into a variable like "data" and then "rename" it to "content:encoded" so this combined data can be viewed in RSS feed.

But I found that if you only combine those two data into a list and rename the list to 
"content:encoded",it won't be recognized. The "content:encoded"'s content format has to be it's format.

So what can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have got the two page contents use a regex module as

In item.content:encoded replace ^.*$ with ${data1.content} ${data2.content}

This will replace content:encoded if it exists or create one if it does not exists